# How to run android Instrument test on Multiple devices at a time

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to run my test cases on 2 devices together.How can I do this via android studios or command line?

Comment: The `connectedCheck` Gradle task should run your tests on all connected devices and emulators, though I have not tried this.

Answer (score -3):

You can select multiple devices each run configuration. Make sure that all devices are listed in adb. Try selecting unselected devices by pressing ctrl button.

Comment: that is working for general classes but not for test cases